# SAP Hybris email velocity template image reference

Tags: java, velocity, apache-commons, sap-commerce-cloud, email-templates

I have .vm file for confirmation order mail and I'm placing some informations to this .vm template. There are several images in these informations. But my images not rendered while the email was sending.
I tried several methods but doesn't work.These are:

`<img src='${ctx.contextPath}/images/theme/social_01.jpg`

`<img src='${ctx.themeResourceUrl}/images/theme/social_01.jpg`

and

`<img src='../images/theme/social_01.jpg`

Any one of these are didn't work for me.

Also my images at the following location of the project:

xxxStore > import > sampledata > contentCatalogxxx > images > theme >

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Edit: My Hybris version is Sap Commerce 1905.

Comment: Yeah! I solved the problem. The "src" attribute in image, should be noted multi ""../../"" instead of '../..' . Because hyrbis console(hac) ignore the tag and create empty or null src. Thanks for your interests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you print the complete image URL in the email and try to open it in the new browser window and see. You should able to access your image. If not, try looking at the URL, is it correct? Let me know the result.

I would suggest you to following any exiting working image, place your image to the same folder, and access it similarly.

---

It seems you are trying to access static image. You can find all frontend static content under the webroot folder of the storefront extension. Your image should be in the same folder as well.

e.g.
I have an image at

```
sastorefront/web/webroot/_ui/responsive/theme-blue/images/test.png
```

I can access it using

```
${themeResourcePath}/images/test.png
```

To debug path issues, I would print the path, and try hitting same URL through the browse. Ideally, an image should be accessible with the URL. Say in my case, I can access test.png with

```
https://example.com/_ui/responsive/theme-blue/images/test.png
```

Comment: I copied my image files to under the base site url. After, I edited variable theme resource path via StringBuilder class in my java context class for accessing from .vm template. But nothing. My themeResourcePath = https://doqu.local:9002/erciyesstorefront/_ui/responsive/theme-doqu. And my footer impex: ${ctx.themeResourcePath}/images/theme/social_01.jpg

Comment: https://doqu.local:9002/erciyesstorefront/_ui/responsive/theme-doqu/images/theme/social_01.jpg

Using this URL, are you able to access your image using browser?

Comment: https://doqu.local:9002/erciyesstorefront/_ui/responsive/theme-doqu/images/social_01.jpg try this URL, I have removed /theme/ from the URL. Also let me know your full folder path where you have copied your image.

Comment: Yes, I can access the image, and I solved the problem by fix my src="" tags. Images are located in mail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your image URL which you are using in VM is corresponding to the actual image URL.

To provide this,

- go to Backoffice media type
- check your media URL